# ipad second start screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

i like to create a second starting screen in my app.
My Idea is to use the `default.png` and load an `UIView` with an fullscreen `UIImageView` inside.

In `viewDidLoad` i thought about placing a sleep option and after this load the real app screen.
But also when my function is called in `viewDidLoad`, nothing happens.

Seems my superview is empty...
Here is a piece of code:

```
if (self._pdfview == nil)
{
    pdfview *videc = [[pdfview alloc] 
                      initWithNibName:@"pdfview" bundle:nil];
    self._pdfview = videc;
    [pdfview release];
}
// get the view that's currently showing
UIView *currentView = self.view;
// get the the underlying UIWindow, or the view containing the current view
UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];
```

`theWindow` is empty after this line so that might be the reason why the other view is not loaded.

So my question, how do i create a second starting screen ?

Or three starting screens, like in games when i like to mention another company.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your point is that when your function above is executed from `viewDidLoad` of some controller, `theWindow` is nil, so your new view (startscreen) is not added to it.

A few observations:

1. if `theWindow` is nil, then `self.view` is the topmost UIView; you can try and replace it, or simply add your view to it:

   ```
   UIView *currentView = self.view;
   // get the the underlying UIWindow, or the view containing the current view
   UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview]; 
   UIView *newView = _pdfview.view;
   if (theWindow) {
     [currentView removeFromSuperview];
     [theWindow addSubview:newView];
   } else {
     self.view = newView; //-- or: [self.view addSubview:newView];
   }
   ```
2. if you want to get the UIWindow of your app (which seems what you are trying to do), you can do:

   ```
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
   ```

and from there you can either set the `rootViewController` (from iOS 4.0)

```
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = ...;
```

or add newView as a subview to it:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:newView];
```

in the second case, you should possibly remove all `subviews` previously added to the `UIWindow`. (Iterate on keyWindow.subviews and call `removeFromSuperview`).

OLD ANSWER:

I think that you should try and add your `pdfview` as a subview to the current view:

```
[currentView addSubview:videc];
```

or to what you call `theWindow`:

```
[theWindow addSubview:pvidec];
```

and, please, move the `release` statement *after* the `addSubview, otherwise the view will be deallocated immediately.

Comment: mmm ty for your answer, to load any view is not my problem. The problem is to create a second startscreen, with any picture.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. To create a second startscreen, what you have to do is load an image, or a nib, and display it on top of your current view. The way to do that is using `addSubview`. In your code, you load `videc`, but then you do not do anything with it, i.e. you do not try to display it...

Comment: i call this function that loads another xib.

Comment: the forum don t let me post the code :( but when i call it from an button it works simply not from viewDidLoad

Comment: -(void) topdf2
{
    if (self._pdfview == nil)
    {
        pdfview *videc = [[pdfview alloc] 
                          initWithNibName:@"pdfview" bundle:nil];
        self._pdfview = videc;
        [pdfview release];
    }
    // get the view that's currently showing
    UIView *currentView = self.view;
    // get the the underlying UIWindow, or the view containing the current view
    UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];

Comment: UIView *newView = _pdfview.view;
    
    [currentView removeFromSuperview];
    [theWindow addSubview:newView];
    
    // set up an animation for the transition between the views
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.8];

Comment: [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    
    [[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];      
}

Comment: meanwhile i solved it with a timer:code:- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // Schedule the timerTicked in 5 seconds
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerTicked) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    
}

Comment: and from here i start my function